# How to link an application classes to F-Script

Tags: objective-c, osx-snow-leopard, f-script

I would like to create a command line application that accepts a script F-Script that is executed, and which has access to some classes exposed by the application.

How can I do that?

**PS**: I am referring to [F-Script](http://www.fscript.org/), not [FScript](http://fscript.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code of FScript.app, which is reported to be linked to most of the Core framework, I found the following method:

```
- (void)loadSystemFrameworks  // Contributed by Cedric Luthi
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSMutableArray *systemFrameworksPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"/System/Library/Frameworks"];

  if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FScriptLoadPrivateSystemFrameworks"])
    [systemFrameworksPaths addObject:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks"];

  for (NSString *systemFrameworksPath in systemFrameworksPaths)
  {
    for (NSString *framework in [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:systemFrameworksPath error:NULL])
    {
      NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[systemFrameworksPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:framework]];
      if ([frameworkBundle preflightAndReturnError:nil])
        [frameworkBundle load];
    }
  }

  [pool drain];
}
```

I take that to link to the classes defined from an application is enough to load the bundle containing the classes.